# Eclipse Oxygen - How can I download remote preference and overwrite local settings?

Tags: eclipse, user-preferences, oomph

I think the documentation is confusing. I have my working environment preferences uploaded to eclipse.org, and now I want to download it to my home machine, with Eclipse Oxygen. How can I do that? "Synchronize now" seems to upload instead of download.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to download remote preferences from **eclipse.org** to your local Eclipse installation. There is an open Eclipse bug on that very issue:

[Bug 476019 - Support synchronization of local user preferences with a remote service](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=476019)

The bug is unresolved but its status is ASSIGNED, so hopefully that feature will be included in some future release of Oomph. It seems that there are legal and privacy issues associated with its implementation, apart from the purely technical aspect.

There is also code for the bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/DuaneNielsen/APMFieldDev/tree/master/plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.sync/src/org/eclipse/oomph/setup/sync), but it doesn't appear to have been touched for a couple of years.

(And I agree that the Oomph documentation is confusing.)

Comment: Well, "legal concern", sigh. I think all technical effort must stop at where the lawyers stand. But at least I can export all preferences by `export`. So not a big issue. But... I think we have now store the user data on Eclipse.org, as far as I am concerned... I can see my data there....

Comment: And at current time, I have seen eclipse.org is saving my data in their site... because every time I use Oomph I am requested my email and password to save data there. So I think it is no more a problem... anyway.